# How do I automatically start the Kestrel web server on Linux sith ASP.NET 5?

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-core

I have ASP.NET 5 running on Linux using NGINX as a proxy. It works fine apart from the fact the kestrel command has to be run from the terminal. I tried adding this as an upstart job in /etc/init

```
description     "Run HelloMvc"

start on startup

task
exec /home/matt/.dnx/runtimes/dnx-mono.1.0.0-beta4/bin/dnx /home/matt/aspnet-tests/HelloMvc kestrel
```

My *nix skills are a bit rudimentary so it might be I'm missing something obvious. Any help appreciated :-)